# Nth max salary query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table; containing 2 fields, name and salary. I used below script to find the 3rd maximum salary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sal 
FROM downtodate1.emp e1  
WHERE 3 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sal) FROM downtodate1.emp e2 WHERE e1.sal<= e2.sal);
```

I want to know how it works and why 3 is used here?

Comment: You are filtering for records "where 3 is the number of distinct salaries to which the current salary is less than or equal".  That is, where there are 3 distinct salaries that are greater than or equal to the current record; remember that the current record itself is one of those three.

Answer (score 4):

```
select distinct sal 
from downtodate1.emp AS e1  
where 3 = (
    select count(distinct sal) 
    from downtodate1.emp e2 
    where e1.sal <= e2.sal
);
```

Consider you have a table like this:

```
sal
---
3
3
2
1
1
0
```

With this part

```
select distinct sal 
from downtodate1.emp AS e1
```

you'll get the result

```
sal
---
3
2
1
0
```

That makes 4 distinct salaries.

Now the subquery

```
    select count(distinct sal) 
    from downtodate1.emp e2 
    where e1.sal <= e2.sal
```

is executed for every row in your main query. It calculates the number of distinct values which are lower or equal the row in your main query. So the result of this is actually (but not displayed):

```
sal | count(distinct sal) where e1.sal <= e2.sal
------------------------------------------------
3     1
3     1
2     2
1     3
1     3
0     4
```

With the distinct from the main query you'll get this result:

```
sal | count(distinct sal) where e1.sal <= e2.sal
------------------------------------------------
3     1
2     2
1     3
0     4
```

and with the `WHERE` clause `3 = (/*subquery*/)` you'll get only

```
sal | count(distinct sal) where e1.sal <= e2.sal
------------------------------------------------
1     3
```

this row. So the result is `1`.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: thinks dear. I understood now.Nice elaboration

Answer (score 1):

Here's a faster method...

```
 SELECT salary
   FROM
      (
        SELECT salary
             , @prev := @curr
             , @curr := salary
             , @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) rank
          FROM employee
         CROSS
          JOIN 
             ( SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
         ORDER 
            BY salary DESC
      ) x
  WHERE rank = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This....

SELECT DISTINCT sal
FROM downtodate1.emp e1
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sal) FROM downtodate1.emp e2 WHERE e1.sal> e2.sal);

WHERE 0 =1st Highest Sal

WHERE 1 =2nd Highest Sal

WHERE 2 =3rd Highest Sal

WHERE 3 =4th Highest Sal

Index start from zero(0)

Instead of this...

SELECT DISTINCT sal
FROM downtodate1.emp e1
WHERE 3 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sal) FROM downtodate1.emp e2 WHERE e1.sal<= e2.sal);

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use this to find the Nth max salary

```
SELECT sal FROM emp
ORDER BY sal DESC
LIMIT N,1
```

N be the Nth number.

Comment: thanks.It will work  but I am interested to know the mechanism of the query which I have asked.

Comment: No, this does not work. Consider you have salaries 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0 in your table. With your query result will be 2, whereas the result should be 1 as the salaries are equal sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reformatting the query will clarify:

```
select distinct sal 
from downtodate1.emp AS e1  
where 3 = (
    select count(distinct sal) 
    from downtodate1.emp e2 
    where e1.sal <= e2.sal
);
```

The result of the subquery is being compared to 3, as the number of preceding rows for the requried row. This is (potentially) a O(N^2) calculation, but that may be sufficient in this case.

Comment: In calculating the time complexity, are you not assuming that there is no B-tree index on `downtodate1.emp.sal`?

Comment: Updated. Yes, optimizations may exist, but one shouldn't assume they are in place. Count() is normally an inefficient operation, when it is not the entire collection.

Comment: how 3 will be compared to sub query.Can you please explain the sub query in this case

Comment: "There is no royal road to knowledge", as Aristotle said to Alexander the Great. Time for you to read your SQL text about scalar-valued sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

this 3 is the same as you writed

```
  where  
(select count(distinct sal) from downtodate1.emp e2 where e1.sal <= e2.sal) = 3 ;
```

where a = 3

or where 3 = the count of distinct sal

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to retrieve maximum salary record of Employee with subQueries

`select * from Employee where salary in (select max(salary) from Employee)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Setup:
    create table employee
    (
        id serial,
        name varchar(150),
        salary float
    );

    insert into employee(name,salary) values ('sagar','100000'),
    ('sangram','50000'),
    ('sachin','56000'),
    ('swapnil','45000'),
    ('gaurav',54000),
    ('ganesh',39000);

    insert into employee(name,salary) values ('gajanan',54000),
    ('kamal',39000);


Nth Max Salary
    select * from employee where salary = (
        select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset n-1
    )
3rd Max salary:
    select * from employee where salary = (
        select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset 2
    )
Nth Max Salary Using Inner Join:
    select s.* from employee s 
    inner join (
        select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset n-1
    ) t on s.salary = t.salary

3rd Max salary:
    select s.* from employee s 
    inner join (
        select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset 2
    ) t on s.salary = t.salary

Nth Max Salary generic:
    select * from employee e1 where n-1=(select count(distinct salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary > e1.salary)

3rd Max Salary:
    select * from employee e1 where 2=(select count(distinct salary) from employee e2 where e2.salary > e1.salary)

Nth Max salary using DENSE_RANK():
    select
        T1.name,
        T1.salary
    from (
        SELECT
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS rownumber,
            Salary,
            name
        FROM
            employee
    )T1  where T1.rownumber = n

3rd Max salary:
    select
        T1.name,
        T1.salary
    from (
        SELECT
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS rownumber,
            Salary,
            name
        FROM
            employee
    )T1  where T1.rownumber = 3



Nth Max salary using ROW_NUMBER():
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS rownumber,Salary
        FROM (select distinct salary from employee)T1
    ) AS foo
    inner join Employee E2 on E2.salary = foo.salary
    WHERE
        rownumber = n   

3rd Max salary:
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS rownumber,Salary
        FROM (select distinct salary from employee)T1
    ) AS foo
    inner join employee E2 on E2.salary = foo.salary
    WHERE
        rownumber = 3
```